# Added token to header when sending json

Tags: c#, json, authentication

I am trying to send some json and am required to add a special token that will need to be added in the headers as:

```
Authorization: Token token=7d20f3f09ef24067ae64f4323bc95163
```

I have tried using this code:

```
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(invitation);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "token=7d20f3f09ef24067ae64f4323bc95163");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

But it just hangs after the last line of code and I never get a response. I have seen all sorts of examples of adding a header with "schemes" such as "Basic" and "Bearer" but can't figure out what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be repeating `token` twice in your header. You may want the following, without the `token=...` key.

```
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "7d20f3f09ef24067ae64f4323bc95163");
```

Comment: Yeah apparently it actually has to be the string token = "... Anyway now I am getting a 404 not found in the response at least.

Comment: @gareth99 you should post your own answer and mark it correct then.

Comment: Huh? It's still not working though. I don't have an answer!

Comment: You solved your token issue. This isn't a forum; Once you've answered the question, you mark it complete. You can ask new questions about your unrelated 404 issues.

Comment: I don't understand why you say it's not a forum. Of course it is. But anyway I will ask another question and take up more space!

Comment: @gareth99 no, it is not, it's Q&A site, not a place for long discussions. You asked a question about http auth which you solved; You should post a formal answer and mark it accepted! The whole point of SO is to ask lots of separate, small questions which have concrete answers.